# Conditional formatting formula to detect duplication in any particular group

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

In the image above, how can I set up a conditional formatting rule to check whether an EAN appears more than once within a particular supplier "group"? I know how to check if an EAN appears twice in a given column but how can I amend this to check if an EAN appears twice within a given group? I am trying to ensure that if a duplicate Supplier - EAN combination is entered then it flags as red. There should never be more than one row with the exact same Supplier-EAN (WK is always WK03 here so irrelevant).

Answer (score 1):

You can use COUNTIFS for counting duplicates for both cells. Selecting range A2:E put this formula as conditional formatting:

```
=COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B2,$D:$D,$D2)>1
```